# Computing Ext: $\text{Ext}(i_* \mathcal{O}_X, i_* \mathcal{O}_X)$ for closed embedding $i:X \rightarrow Y$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector bundle on $X$, and $Y = \text{Tot}(V)$ be the total space of this bundle; we have a closed embedding $i: X \rightarrow Y$. Why is the following result true?

$$ \text{Ext}^k(i_* \mathcal{O}_X,i_* \mathcal{O}_X) = \bigoplus_{i+j=k} H^i(X, \Lambda^j V)$$

Comment: Why do you believe it's true?

Comment: Does this work if X is a point?

Answer (score 6):

Let $\pi :Y\rightarrow X$ be the projection. The bundle  $\pi ^*V$ has a canonical section $s$ (the diagonal, if you think of $\pi ^*V$ as $V\times _XV$), which vanishes exactly along $i(X)$. Thus $i_*\mathcal{O}_X$ has a Koszul resolution
$$ \ldots \rightarrow \wedge^2\pi ^*V^*\rightarrow \pi ^*V^* {\buildrel {s}\over {\longrightarrow}}\ \mathcal{O}_Y\rightarrow i_*\mathcal{O}_X$$
by locally free $\mathcal{O}_Y$-modules. Applying 
 $\ \underline{\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(-,i_*\mathcal{O}_X)$ kills the differentials, so we get
 $R\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(i_*\mathcal{O}_X,i_*\mathcal{O}_X)\cong \oplus \
 \wedge^pV[p]$, then $R\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(i_*\mathcal{O}_X,i_*\mathcal{O}_X)\cong \oplus R\Gamma (\wedge^pV[p])$,  hence the result by applying $H^k$.